# add css class to image attached in all the posts?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

In wordpress Currently by default image attachment have similar classes

```
<img class="size-full wp-image-8996" src="https://nepaltimes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/31043884_1792179470828697_8330507756888915968_n.jpg">
```

**What i am trying here to add a class as img-fluid to all the attachments in posts not the thumbnails.**

```
<img class="img-fluid size-full wp-image-8996" src="https://nepaltimes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/31043884_1792179470828697_8330507756888915968_n.jpg">
```

How could it be done?
Any Idea will be appreciated!
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of modifying all of your posts or applying the 'img-fluid' class dynamically, perhaps consider using CSS3 selectors to apply the same styles to all of your image attachments using an existing class.  For example you could use:

```
img[class*='wp-image-']
```

This targets all image elements on the page which include 'wp-image-' in the class attribute.  Here is an example:

```css
img[class*='wp-image-'] {
   width: 25%;
   height: 25%;
   opacity: 0.5;
   border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<img class="size-full wp-image-8996" src="https://nepaltimes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/31043884_1792179470828697_8330507756888915968_n.jpg" />
```

Finally, if you ***need*** to use the specific class 'img-fluid', if for example you are integrating Bootstrap into an existing site, you could use SASS to extend the 'img-fluid' selector using a selector that works with the class names already on the img tags.  Here's an example:

```
img[class*='wp-image-'] {
  @extend .img-fluid;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Your idea helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can get this in several ways.

> In wordpress if you are theming your custom website, then you have option to take the url of your image not whole image tag generated by wordpress function like.

```
<img class="img-fluid size-full wp-image-8996" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>"/>
```

> Other way to do that is by using javascript you can add your custom class on document load event.